# Как узнать сколько оперативной памяти тратит вкладка в браузере

Tags: google-chrome

Я пользуюсь браузером Google Chrome и я хотел бы узнать, сколько тратит оперативной памяти открытая вкладка в Chrome, я думаю это есть где-то в DevTools, но не нашёл, подскажите

Comment: bash command: `top`

Comment: Диспетчер вкладок

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перейдите по ссылке chrome://system/, затем нажмите кнопку Expand для раздела mem_usage, после чего справа будет показан список открытых вкладок (окон) с данными по используемой памяти оными. Пример вывода:

```
Browser 132 MB private, 72 MB shared
Tab [YouTube] 91 MB private, 68 MB shared
Tab [Wall | VK] 58 MB private, 78 MB shared
Tab [google chrome - Как узнать сколько оперативной памяти тратит вкладка в браузере - Stack Overflow на русском] 46 MB private, 70 MB shared
GPU [] 30 MB private, 28 MB shared
Tab (Chrome) [chrome://system] 13 MB private, 57 MB shared
```

---

Подробнее о "тайных" полезных страницах по Google Chrome можно почитать здесь https://vk.com/wall-176103573_139